# Where does a throttling Error appear in the SMPP protocol?

Tags: sms, throttling, smpp

Which command (submit_sm, deliver_sm ...) will result with the appearence of the error?
There are many commands, it will be helpful, if someone has a good link to a page (documentation), in which this theme is explained well.

Comment: In submit_sm where you send more requests to the SMSC then it is configured as threshold

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [SMPP v 3.4](https://smpp.org/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) section 5.1.3:

> The command_status field of an SMPP message response indicates the success or failure of an
>   SMPP request. **It is relevant only in the SMPP response message** and should be set to NULL in
>   SMPP request messages.
>   The SMPP Error status codes are returned by the SMSC in the command_status field of the
>   SMPP message header and in the error_status_code field of a submit_multi_resp message.
>   The complete set of SMPP Error Codes and their associated values are defined in the following
>   table.

If you scroll down to the Error codes you will see:

> ESME_RTHROTTLED -> 0x00000058 -> Throttling error (ESME has exceeded
>   allowed message limits)

So to answer you question short on all A2P or A2A (submit_sm, submit_multi, deliver_sm).